# Error unexpected token near "SELECT" at position 160

Tags: mysql, request

I'm trying to do this query to update a table with data selected from another table

```
INSERT INTO `sterap_produit_non_steril_beta` (`id`, `loc`, `nsn`, `descrip_nl`, `descrip_fr`, `marque`, `ref`) VALUES (NULL, 'loca', 'nsn', '', 'ald', '', '')
SELECT `nsn`,`ald`,`qt`,`loca` FROM `stock_mhns` WHERE `loca`<> '' AND `nsn` NOT IN (SELECT nsn FROM `sterap_produit_non_steril_beta` );
```

When I try the queries separately, no problem !!
But both I have an

> Error "Unexpected Token. (Near" SELECT ""

I'm not a sql specialist but I can't see the syntax error
Thanks for your help
Stephane

Comment: You have 2 queries in a single line, you have to seperate them with `;` `..'', ''); SELECT..`

Comment: Are you inserting from `VALUES ()` or `SELECT` results ?

Comment: I want to make an insert from my select

Comment: If you want to insert values from your `SELECT` you have to remove the `VALUES` statement. Then the format will looks like `INSERT INTO Table (f1, f2..) SELECT null, f2 FROM table2 WHERE...`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to introduce the data from the select query in the sterap_produit_non_steril_beta table
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please use next query for insert selected data:

```
INSERT INTO `sterap_produit_non_steril_beta` (
     `id`, `loc`, `nsn`, `descrip_nl`, `descrip_fr`, `marque`, `ref`
) SELECT NULL, `loca`, `nsn`, '', `ald`, '', '' 
FROM `stock_mhns` 
WHERE
    `loca`<> '' AND
    `nsn` NOT IN (
        SELECT nsn FROM `sterap_produit_non_steril_beta`
    );
```